# what does 'if x.strip( )' mean?

Tags: python, if-statement, strip

So I was having problems with a code before because I was getting an empty line when I iterated through the foodList.

Someone suggested using the 'if x.strip():' method as seen below.

```
for x in split:
  if x.strip():
    foodList = foodList + [x.split(",")]
```

It works fine but I would just like to know what it actually means. I know it deletes whitespace, but wouldn't the above if statement be saying if x had empty space then true. Which would be the opposite of what I wanted? Just would like to wrap my ahead around the terminology and what it is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: It means: "if the string is not only white space" (more exactly: "if the string, after having being stripped of any whitespace on both sides, contains some character..."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Python, "empty" objects --- empty list, empty dict, and, as in this case, empty string --- are considered false in a boolean context (like `if`).  Any string that is not empty will be considered true.  `strip` returns the string after stripping whitespace.  If the string contains only whitespace, then `strip()` will strip everything away and return the empty string.  So `if strip()` means "if the result of `strip()` is not an empty string" ---  that is, if the string contains something besides whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

> The method strip() returns a copy of the string in which all chars
>   have been stripped from the beginning and the end of the string
>   (default whitespace characters).

So, it trims whitespace from begining and end of a string if no input char is specified. At this point, it just controls whether string `x` is empty or not without considering spaces because an `empty` string is interpreted as `false` in python

Answer (score 0):

Simply, this syntax is used when a user can enter some data and you want to make sure that the user has entered something, rather than nothing.

Let's simplify it more:

- case(1): `x.strip()` is empty , meaning the user didn't enter anything. In this case `x.strip()` is `False` because empty strings are "Falsey"
- case(2): `x.strip()` is not empty, meaning the user did enter something (other than spaces). In this case `x.strip()` will return the string with whitespace trailing and preceding removed, which is "Truthy".